# Can I specify the order of yielded instances using keras ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to merge two models,  one is an LSTM that needs an order on a numpy series somehow (I found the appropriate order). This model, along with a convolution model that accepts a flow of images using flow_from_directory.

knowing that order of input of one model is a constraint, I want to order the flow of images ids from directory so that they could learn something together.

Here is my implementation so far without a specific order on

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

input_imgen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, 
                                   shear_range = 0.2, 
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   rotation_range=5.,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_imgen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

def slice_and_order(gen, cut):
  for i in gen:
    idx = (gen.batch_index - 1) * gen.batch_size
    filenames = gen.filenames #[idx : idx + gen.batch_size]
    filenames = [int(filename.split('/')[1].split('.')[0]) for filename in filenames]
    print(filenames)
    current = int(gen.filenames[idx].split('/')[1].split('.')[0])
    print(current)
    if(current in range(cut[0], cut[1])):
      yield i

def generate_generator_multiple(generator,dir1, cut, batch_size, img_height,img_width):
    genX1 = generator.flow_from_directory(dir1,
                                          target_size = (img_height,img_width),
                                          class_mode = 'categorical',
                                          batch_size = batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          seed=7)
    genX1_ = slice_and_order(genX1, cut)
    with tf.Session() as session:
        res = bounding_boxes(cut)
        genX2 = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
            res['x'], res['y'], batch_size=2, shuffle=False, num_epochs=1)


    while True:
        val = next(genX1_)
        features, target = genX2()

        yield [val[0], features], target  #Yield both images and their mutual label

_20_ = (14104 // 5)
train_cut = [0, _20_ * 3]
test_cut =  [train_cut[1], train_cut[1] + _20_]
validation_cut = [test_cut[1], 14104]

inputgenerator=generate_generator_multiple(generator=input_imgen,
                                           dir1="images/",
                                           cut=train_cut,
                                           batch_size=1,
                                           img_height=96,
                                           img_width=96)       

validgenerator=generate_generator_multiple(test_imgen,
                                          dir1="images/",
                                          cut=validation_cut,
                                          batch_size=1,
                                          img_height=96,
                                          img_width=96)
```

`slice_and_order` should order `genX1` although it doesn't for now.